# onClick and console.log on Nextjs is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, xml, next.js

I'm learning NEXT and there are functions that don't work

```
"use client"

import { useState } from 'react'
export default function idk() {
    const [counter,setCounter]=useState(0)
    const add=()=>{
        setCounter(prev=>prev+1)
    }
    return(
            <div onClick={add}>
               {counter}
            </div>
    )
}
```

When the code is run, it creates the initial state of the counter but there is no change after that

I thought the problem was in the Hooks, but even the console doesn't work

```
"use client"

export default function idk() {
    const ttc=()=>{ 
       console.log("i try to console")
    }
    return(
            <button onClick={ttc}> CLICK me </button >
    )
}
```

routing The page does not redirect directly, but rather reloads as if I were using several html pages

```
<Link href="/about"> about </Link>
```

This problem has been occurring since the first use of next

I do not think that the problem is in the code, but rather in my version, and there are notes that may help you understand my problem :

**The same code works in react.js**

**When I create an application, I choose src in the settings**

**Sometimes the page becomes white and does not show the problem**

`Node version: v17.1.0`

`npm  version:8.1.2`

`next version: @latest`

I don't know, but I tried to create the project again and some problems that I did not mention went away

Comment: Have you checked your browser console and the terminal for errors? Also, rename `idk` to `Idk`, as a React component should start with a capital letter.

Comment: I wrote the code in StackOverflow so I didn't check the name 

The console did not give me any error, and if the problem was there, then why did the useState not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to downgrade your next version to `13.4.16`

Comment: This answer is also not clear at all it just gives a suggestion but it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

@wantToBeAProgrammer
Thanks you really solved all the problems

To anyone who has the same problem, **changing the version to a more stable version may solve your problems**

If you want to know how to change the version of the next:

1. delete node_modules folder
2. from `package.json` file change the **dependencies** and set the version you want :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.16",
    "next": "13.4.16",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
```

3. run `npm install` again